# TypeScript: Limit discriminator in discriminated union from other string literal union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, discriminated-union

I have a very basic discriminated union, but for the discriminator, I only want to allow a specific values that are coming from another string literal union type. This would make it easier to add new union "cases" to the discriminated union.

Here's a string literal union which describes the allowed "values" for the type:

```
type AllowedType = "typeForNumber" | "typeForBoolean"
```

Then, my type to describe the data uses that string literal union:

```
type Data = {
  type: AllowedType,
  value: number | boolean
}
```

Based on my example, there are two options, which can have a more specific type for `value` based on their `type` field. I don't use these options, they're just here for demonstration purposes:

```ts
// Option 1 - "value" is a "number"
type DataOption1 = {
  type: "typeForNumber",
  value: number
}
// Option 2 - "value" is a "boolean"
type DataOption2 = {
  type: "typeForBoolean",
  value: boolean
}
```

So what I actually want to do is a discriminated union for `Data`, because I can give more specific types for its `value` field that way:

```
type Data =
  | {
      type: "typeForNumber"
      value: number
    }
  | {
      type: "typeForBoolean"
      value: boolean
    }
```

When you use the type, everything works fine:

```
const myData: Data = {
  type: "typeForNumber",
  // this creates an error, should be a `number`
  value: "some string"
}
```

**My question is: How do I make sure that the `type` field in my `Data` type can only be one of the options of the `AllowedType`?**

In the future, there will be more options for `AllowedType`, so I want to limit the possible union types with them.

One could change add another union to the `Data` type like so, without any error:

```
type Data =
  | {
      type: "typeForNumber"
      value: number
    }
  | {
      type: "typeForBoolean"
      value: boolean
    }
  | {
      type: "someOtherType"
      value: string
    }
```

This new union (with `type: "someOtherType"`) shouldn't be allowed.

Is it possible to limit the discriminator (`type`) in this discriminated union (`Data`) from other string literal union type (`AllowedType`)?

I tried to use a wrapper for the intersection, but the unions ignore (overwrite?) the `type` type:

```
type AllowedType = "typeForNumber" | "typeForBoolean"

type DataWrapper = {
  type: AllowedType
  value: number | boolean
}

type Data = DataWrapper &
  (
    | {
        type: "typeForNumber"
        value: number
      }
    | {
        type: "typeForBoolean"
        value: boolean
      }
  )
```

Comment: *"This new union (with type: "someOtherType") shouldn't be allowed."* Why not? Because of its value of `type`, or its type of `value`? (I ask because if it's because it uses a `type` that isn't in `AllowedType`, there is a really simple solution for that -- turn things around, define `Data` and derive `AllowedType` from it: `type AllowedType = Data["type"];`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the issue is `Data` and `AllowedType` possibly getting out of sync. If that's the issue, you could turn things around and define `AllowedType` in terms of `Data`, like this:

```typescript
type Data =
  | {
      type: "typeForNumber"
      value: number
    }
  | {
      type: "typeForBoolean"
      value: boolean
    };

type AllowedType = Data["type"];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8BYAUFKAfKBvDLIqUSALigCJSIAxAewCcA5AVwFsAjCRyw4qADc4AG1YQKAOw7dG-LAF9+uApgE0K1cHSYAhevREQ4kvmuLCxEqJwNGT8qAoDcGDDSgBBESPoB3CAATABVtFFgEOABtLUhKAF1nIA)

Then, adding to `Data` automatically adds to `AllowedType`.

---

In a comment you've said you're trying to protect against typos in the `type` of the `Data` union:

> In my case, the Data type represents dynamic data coming from another source, so I want to be sure that there are e.g. no typos in the type values (like typeForNumber). That's why I'm so keen to find a solution to limit the type to specific values. Turning it around doesn't help in my case.

This seems to help with that:

```typescript
type CheckData<DataType extends {type: AllowedType}> =
    Exclude<DataType["type"], AllowedType> extends never
        ? DataType
        : never;
```

Then this works:

```typescript
type Data = CheckData<
    | {
        type: "typeForNumber"
        value: number
    }
    | {
        type: "typeForBoolean"
        value: boolean
    }>;
```

but this doesn't:

```typescript
type Data2 = CheckData<
    | {
        type: "typeForNumber"
        value: number
    }
    | {
        type: "typeForBoolean"
        value: boolean
    }
    | {
        type: "typeForSomethingElse"
        value: boolean
    }>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnA9gdwgEwCrmgXigIlEgDFEAnAOQFcBbAIwjPygB8CiJSyAhRROCAEMAdvgDcAWABQ0jlADCACwgBjANYARQcEEAeLTqyQoEAB7AIwtAGcoAbw4AuWAhTojEAL4A+KHgCipipwVGgQ+tqCHgDahNj4ALoANC5IqJjYvmYWVrbCEABujFAA-FAGUdhQzvlFZJIyUnIVfgrK6hW60lA9rPbdvYNO7Nhc1PSM+AODPQWCIRA1tAxk01Cea2x2a0PYznEk5Lz8QqI7vXMLznR8AiJrPg2yVRUATK1KqpqRXVKDW+cesMDpxyOMVlM-jNZvMqIsoMJlowHpt+lDocCOFxjnczuiZpc4ddbqcUfiAfjdpB9ljyABlRA0CDARQAS2EAHN-HBrBBIdCYVcoDcTvd8Y9pEA)

It doesn't catch **all** typos, though. It allows two types that both use the same `type` value.

Comment: This works great for keeping them in sync, but it would turn the responsibility around, right? I would like to make it easier to add new unions to `Data` by only allowing specific values via `AllowedType` - what you're proposing is "generating" `AllowedType` from all the unions.

Comment: @BennettDams - Yes, that's what I mean by "turn it around." It works for a lot of use cases, but of course I don't know whether it works for yours. Coming at it from the other direction is (I think) quite difficult.

Comment: In my case, the `Data` type represents dynamic data coming from another source, so I want to be sure that there are e.g. no typos in the `type` values (like `typeForNumber`). That's why I'm so keen to find a solution to limit the `type` to specific values. Turning it around doesn't help in my case.

Comment: @BennettDams - How do you avoid typos in `AllowedType`?

Comment: @BennettDams - I've added to the answer, though for me it sort of begs the question of how to avoid the issue I call out with it (repeating the same `type`) which I don't immediately know how to solve. :-)

Comment: _How do you avoid typos in AllowedType?_  I can't with either approach, but when the ´AllowedType` is the source of truth, at least I have everything in one place instead of scattered through the unions.